# how to specify topic name when to list metric descriptor in gcp

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, metrics, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using  monitoring "cloud.google.com/go/monitoring/apiv3" and "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/monitoring/v3" and request is

```
req := &monitoringpb.ListMetricDescriptorsRequest{
        Name:   fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s", t.projectId),
        Filter: "?",
}
```

Comment: is it done in filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can specify the filter. And for Pub Sub Topic Name, i have used the below and it works.

```
"filter": 'metric.type = "pubsub.googleapis.com/topic/send_message_operation_count" AND resource.type = "pubsub_topic" AND resource.labels.topic_id = "<topic name>"'
```

```
Filter: `metric.type="pubsub.googleapis.com/topic/send_message_operation_count" AND resource.type = "pubsub_topic" AND resource.labels.topic_id = "<topic_name>"`
```

Here are a few documentation links which can help on [Metric details related to pub sub](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-pubsub), [listing its descriptors](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.metricDescriptors/list) or you may also try out with [API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/apis-explorer) to check with the required filter for [undelivered messages](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring#monitoring_forwarded_undeliverable_messages)

Tried with below script in Python and it gives me results(project name and topic name ,interval to be changed according to your requirement):

```
import argparse
import os
import pprint
import time
import uuid

from google.api import label_pb2 as ga_label
from google.api import metric_pb2 as ga_metric
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3

client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
project_name = "projects/<project name>"
interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval()

now = time.time()
seconds = int(now)
nanos = int((now - seconds) * 10 ** 9)
interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval(
    {
        "end_time": {"seconds": seconds, "nanos": nanos},
        "start_time": {"seconds": (seconds - 36000000), "nanos": nanos},
    }
)
results = client.list_time_series(
    request={
        "name": project_name,
        "filter": 'metric.type = "pubsub.googleapis.com/topic/send_message_operation_count" AND resource.type = "pubsub_topic" AND resource.labels.topic_id = "<topicname>"',
        "interval": interval,
        "view": monitoring_v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL,
    }
)
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Comment: Also just want to add one more point, ListMetricDescriptorRequest would only give us the list of metrics we have for the specified filter. In this case pubsub.googleapis.com/topic/byte_cost etc.,

Comment: thanks for answering. but it seems like it does not support to add specific topic to this metric. I just want to monitor undelivered message under one specific topic

Comment: Hi Tom, so if i understand your requirement is to read the metrics data of a particular resource.(in this case pubsub topic) which i think can be done by referring to  https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/reading-metrics#monitoring_read_timeseries_simple-python - This example shows monitoring cpu utilization of instance. Similar to this if there is built in metrics for monitoring undelivered message of topic we can use that otherwise options seems like we need to create our own custom metrics.

Comment: yes, but i just tried to use filter like this but it does not work:   "Filter: fmt.Sprintf("resource.subscription_id ==\"%s\"", topic.Name)"

Comment: @Tom Wang - May be you can try this way 1. Filter: fmt.Sprintf("metric.type=\"%s\"", metricType) 
 or  Filter: `metric.type="compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization"`  . Filters can be like metric.type = "compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/usage_time"
AND (metric.label.instance_name = "your-instance-id" OR
  metric.label.instance_name = "your-other-instance-id") if for specific instance. You can change accordingly for the pub sub resource

Comment: [https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/HEAD/monitoring/snippets/time_series_fields.go]   [https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/HEAD/monitoring/custommetric/custommetric.go]

Comment: i have tried "metric.type" but it does not support me to add topic name to it.

Comment: @TomWang - You can use below filter and provide the topic name  "filter": 'metric.type = "pubsub.googleapis.com/topic/send_message_operation_count" AND resource.type = "pubsub_topic" AND resource.labels.topic_id = "<topic name>"'